# checking for alphanumeric and special characters in a string

Tags: c#, regex

The requirement in my project is to check a string for following conditions:

1. It must contain at least one letter (a-z or A-Z)
2. It must contain at least one number (0-9)
3. It must not contain any special characters.

Is there any regular expression that can match all these conditions ?

Here is the code I am using for this

```
private bool IsValidFormat(string str)
{
   Regex rgx = new Regex(@"^[A-Za-z]+\d+.*$");
   return rgx.IsMatch(str);
}
```

It is working for point# 1 and 2 above but it is allowing special characters.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So basically, only alphanumeric characters, with a minimum of one letter and one digit?

Comment: Your current regex will not work for string like "123password", because it expects chars come first

Comment: @MarkCiliaVincenti... yes minimum of 1 character and 1 digit but no special characters.... the sequence of characters or digits is not important

Comment: @AleksAndreev...  the sequence of characters or digits is not important... it may be character first or digit first... I am not much aware of regex... that's the issue

Comment: See https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html really helpful for making your own RegEx. Try the following, '(\d|[A-Za-z])+' simply matches only digits or letters.

Comment: Also, if your curious why your current Regex doesn't work, the '.' matches ANYTHING, then the '*' matches that 0 or more times. So you can basically have anything you want, 0 or more times, which is why you can match special characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following change allows at least one letter, at least one digit and no other characters. The order of letters and digits is not important, unlike the solution offered in the OP where it requires that it starts with a letters and ends with numbers.

```
private bool IsValidFormat(string str)
{
   Regex rgx = new Regex(@"^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$");
   return rgx.IsMatch(str);
}
```